Woocommerce check if product attribute has archive enabled or disabled
I am trying to optimize my cache, and I need to check whether a product attribute has archive page enabled or not. If not, I don't need to purge the cache for that term's url.
Currently, my caching script checks all the terms in a post, and clears the cache for every term permalink, but with products having 20+ product attributes, this is an unnecessary bloat as most of these terms don't show a public page on my website.
So, for each product attribute term, I would need to check if the term's parent has archive enabled or disabled, and when it's disabled, continue to the next term without adding that term's link to the cache purge list.
I have not found anywhere on the internet how to get a product attribute term and check its parent to see it has archive enabled.
Thanks a lot

A $taxonomy->public property holds an archive setting.
The term's parent name is specified in $term->taxonomy and the WP_Taxonomy object can be retrieved using get_taxonomy($name):
$term = get_term( $id );
$taxonomy = get_taxonomy( $term->taxonomy );
$archive_enabled = $taxonomy->public;

